# How do I use both && and || in an if statement

Tags: java, binary-operators

I'm working on a rock paper scissors gui application and I'm stuck on how I can get this to work. I found that in line 49 I get an illegal start of expression error. While I realize this is an assignment, I'm not sure what is triggering the error:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Rps extends JFrame
 implements ActionListener
{
private final char moves[] = {'R', 'P', 'S'};
private JRadioButton rock, paper, scissors;
private JTextField display;

public Rps()
{
super("Rock, paper, Scissors");

rock = new JRadioButton("   Rock   ", true);
paper = new JRadioButton("   Paper  ");
scissors = new JRadioButton(" Scissors ");

ButtonGroup rpsButtons = new ButtonGroup();
rpsButtons.add(rock);
rpsButtons.add(paper);
rpsButtons.add(scissors);

JButton go = new JButton("         Go         ");
go.addActionListener(this);

display = new JTextField(25);
display.setEditable(false);
display.setBackground(Color.yellow);

Container c = getContentPane();
c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
c.add(rock);
c.add(paper);
c.add(scissors);
c.add(go);
c.add(display);
}

/**
*  returns -1 if the player wins,
*  0 if it's a tie, and 1 if the computer wins
*/
private int nextPlay(char computerMove, char playerMove)
{
if (computerMove == 'R'&&playerMove == 'S'||computerMove=='S'&&playerMove==='P'||computerMove=='P'&&playerMove=='R'){ //Where I get the error
 int r = 1;
 return r;
 }
else if (computerMove == 'R'&&playerMove == 'R'||computerMove=='S'&&playerMove=='S'||computerMove=='P'&&playerMove=='P'){
 int r = 0;
 return r;
}
else if (computerMove == 'S'&&playerMove == 'R'||computerMove=='P'&&playerMove=='S'||computerMove=='R'&&playerMove=='P'){
 int r = -1;
 return r;
}
```

}

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  char playerMove, computerMove;
  if (rock.isSelected())
    playerMove = 'R';
  else if (paper.isSelected())
    playerMove = 'P';
  else if (scissors.isSelected())
    playerMove = 'S';

 int k = (int)(Math.random() * 3);
computerMove = moves[k];
int result = nextPlay(computerMove, playerMove);

String msg = "  You said " + makeWord(playerMove) + ", I said " +
             makeWord(computerMove);
if (result < 0)
  msg += " -- you win.";
else if (result == 0)
  msg += " -- tie.";
else if (result > 0)
  msg += " -- I win.";
display.setText(msg);
}

private String makeWord(char move)
{
  String word = "";

switch (move)
{
  case 'R': word = "ROCK"; break;
  case 'P': word = "PAPER"; break;
  case 'S': word = "SCISSORS"; break;
}
return word;
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Rps window = new Rps();
  window.setBounds(300, 300, 300, 140);
  window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  window.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: use `==` instead of `=`

Comment: There is not need to define variable called `r`, assign to it and then return it. You can just use `return 1`.

Comment: You would do well to add parenthesis into your `if` condition to make it clearer exactly what conditions you're testing for.  Also, as @nachokk pointed out, you need `==` not `=`

Comment: @ffarquet Dude, the guy is still in school, give him a break. Why don't you edit his question and format the code appropriately, then explain him why coding standards matter?

Comment: One of your `if` statements has `===` in it.  That's legal in JavaScript and PHP, but not Java.

Answer (score 3):

What you have used is `assignment` operator `=`
You need to use `comparison` operator `==` in your `if` block.

`if (computerMove == 'R'&& playerMove =='S'||computerMove=='S'&&playerMove=='P'|| computerMove=='P'&& playerMove=='R')`

Edit:

There is typo

`playerMove==='P'` in your `if` statement

Comment: It's worth pointing out that parentheses are not needed (although they might clarify the logic), due to the fact that `&&` has higher [precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) than `||`.

Comment: Alright, I fixed that, however I get an illegal start of expression error.

Comment: @SajanChandran I just edited the question to include the full code

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 if ((computerMove == 'R'&&playerMove == 'S')||(computerMove=='S'&&playerMove=='P')||(computerMove=='P'&&playerMove=='R')){
     int r = 1;
     return r;
     }
else if ((computerMove == 'R'&&playerMove = 'R')||(computerMove=='S'&&playerMove=='S')||(computerMove=='P'&&playerMove=='P')){
 int r = 0;
 return r;
}
else if ((computerMove == 'S'&&playerMove == 'R')||(computerMove=='P'&&playerMove=='S')||(computerMove=='R'&&playerMove=='P')){
 int r = -1;
 return r;
```

Comment: While it works, I get an illegal start of expression error on line 49

Answer (score 0):

Besides what others have said about using == instead of =, I would just use parenthesis. Doesn't hurt anything, and improves readability of the code. So your statements would look something like:

```
if (
(computerMove == 'R'&&playerMove =='R') ||
(computerMove=='S'&&playerMove=='S') ||
(computerMove=='P'&&playerMove=='P')
)...
```

Comment: I actually grabbed the block from one of your else blocks (the draw scenario), but you get the idea :)

Comment: This works, however I get an error in line 49 saying that it's an illegal start of an expression.

Comment: @Showman I think you put in one too many `=` signs.  I saw an `===` in your code (after you edited it, I think).